# We need a printer for ubuntu 12.10. How do I know it will be recognized by ubuntu?

Tags: printing

I am having numerous problems with Linux OS and Ubuntu recognizing printers. I am in the process of purchasing a new printer and would appreciate any guidance on compatibility. What printer will be recognized by Ubuntu?

Comment: In its current form this is not a _question_. Please edit into a single understandable question like  "I have [this] printer, will it work with Ubuntu?" or "How can I get [this] printer to work with Ubuntu?" then we will be able to help you.  I am currently flagging this for closure.  If you edit it into a good question it will not be closed.

Comment: seriously? i feel like im sitting in school.

Comment: I was in a hurry and thought I asked the question clearly.  Now that I have edited my question with proper English, perhaps I will get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

just head to ubuntu.com

[Official Ubuntu list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters)

[FSF list (for open source systems)](http://h-node.org/printers/catalogue/en)